# Efficiently remove all but top n rows in a Mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a large, high traffic table with about 10000 entries and i need a command to clear all but the top (**highest ids**) n entries.

I wanted something like this, but it caused a syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE table 
PARTITION BY RANGE(id)(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (MAX(id)-n),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));
ALTER TABLE table DROP PARTITION p0;
```

The only problem is i need to clear all but the top values a lot and stacking partitions doesn't work. Also, a scheduler doesn't fit in well with what im doing.
How can i efficiently remove all but the n highest id rows in a Mysql table?

Comment: Also it says "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it efficiently, then copy the rows into another table, truncate the original table, and insert the rows back in.

```
create temporary table tosave as
    (select *
     from mytable
     order by id desc
     limit n
    );

truncate table mytable;

insert into mytable
    select * from tosave
```

The `truncate` is more efficient because it does not log the deletes (as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html)).

Comment: For 10000 entries and n being 2000, this took ~.13 sec

Comment: I'm surprised this took so much longer than the delete method.  Truncate should work better when you have really large tables, measured in millions of rows.

Comment: its about 10 times faster, what do you mean? thats .13 sec not 13 sec

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
DELETE
FROM ids
WHERE id NOT IN (select * from (select id from ids order by id desc limit 2) s)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f827a/1).

Or also this:

```
DELETE ids.*
FROM
  ids LEFT JOIN (select id from ids order by id desc limit 2) s
  ON ids.id = s.id
WHERE s.id is null
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36784/1).

Comment: for 10000 entries and n being 2000, this took 1.1394 sec

Comment: This might be the most ineffective query ever, but finally something that works. It does not give the "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'" error.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this:

```
delete from `table`
where `key` not in (select `key` from `table` order by <...> limit n,100000)
```